# Can Knapsack algorithms be implemented in Column major form?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I searched for Knapsack algorithm on the net, and in all the implementations, I saw that the 2D array is of the form:

```
 int K[n+1][W+1];
```

where n is the number of elements and W is the maximum weight which can be accommodated in the Knapsack.

This array was filled in a bottom up manner, in a row major format. Can it even be done in a column major format?

Comment: One general advantage of accessing 2D array elements in row major form is to utilize cache locality. This is because in many languages array elements are stored in memory in row major form. This results in more of cache hits and hence better efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly the only requirement on the order in which the array is filled is that, if a <= b and c <= d, then the (a,c) cell is not filled after the (b,d) cell. This follows from tracing the data dependencies of the dynamic program. Row-major, column-major, and many other fill orders are possible.